# Can't reinstall some removed windows 7 updates

Tags: windows-7, windows-update, updates

I have removed some important windows updates (such as KB3139852) and want to reinstall them. But the update cannot be found again after clicking check for update. It just showed `no important updates` and I have checked there is no hidden updates.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: is the question answered?

Comment: ok, in this case [you can accept my reply as answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) to "close" the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Update KB3139852 was replaced in the April 2016 Patchday with Update [KB3145739](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/library/security/ms16-039):

> **Updates Replaced**
>  3139852 in MS16-034

This means the update is fully replaced/superseded and no longer required and Windows Updates skips it and doesn't offer it again.